# Interpreting Anomaly detection R values

Tags: r, anomaly-detection

I have an assignment in which I need to detect anomalies in a dataset. I'm using the 'anomalize' package in R and was wondering how to interpret the following output values of the 'anomalize' function:

Remainder_L1
Remainder_L2

I've checked the documentation but I'm unable to find the calculation method for these values. Can someone explain this calculation?

[Anomalize output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MoGLu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [anomolize documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/anomalize/vignettes/anomalize_quick_start_guide.html) gives a great example of how to apply `anomolize()` to a time series

This generates the `Remainder_L1` and `Remainder_L2` values for CRAN tidyverse downloads (that data comes with the anomolize package, so no need to import data, just run the code below to see how it generates the columns

```r
# install.packages("anomalize")

library(tidyverse)
library(tibbletime)
library(anomalize)


tidyverse_cran_downloads %>%
    time_decompose(count, merge = TRUE) %>%
    anomalize(remainder) 

 #   package date       count observed season trend remainder remainder_l1 remainder_l2 anomaly
 #   <chr>   <date>     <dbl>    <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>        <dbl>        <dbl> <chr>  
 # 1 broom   2017-01-01  1053    1053. -1007. 1708.    352.         -1725.        1704. No     
 # 2 broom   2017-01-02  1481    1481    340. 1731.   -589.         -1725.        1704. No     
 # 3 broom   2017-01-03  1851    1851    563. 1753.   -465.         -1725.        1704. No     
 # 4 broom   2017-01-04  1947    1947    526. 1775.   -354.         -1725.        1704. No     
 # 5 broom   2017-01-05  1927    1927    430. 1798.   -301.         -1725.        1704. No
```

What do these values mean? From the [anomolize source code](https://github.com/business-science/anomalize/blob/master/R/anomalize.R#L25-L26) we see:

> "remainder_l1" (lower limit for anomalies), "remainder_l2" (upper limit for anomalies)

In the example above, it's saying in the first row, `anomolize()` would treat the value (1053) as an anomoly if it was less than -1725, or greater than 1725.